# How to implement Multi-line/AutoResizing UITextView when new line added in xamarin.ios, similar to SMS-app or Skype app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are working on a chat application in xamarin.ios, so here we want to  implement a auto growing textview when new line added like sms or Skype app. How to implement this in xamarin.ios. I have done many R&D on this and many search in internet but not got any proper solution yet.

Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: Hi, I am working on it. Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi We got another simple solution for this also.

```
textview.Changed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>                 
{      
 //Action                     
var NewHeight = txtMsgToSend.ContentSize.Height;                    
textview.Frame = new CGRect(x:textview.Frame.X, y: textview.Frame.Y,  width:  
textview.Frame.Width, height: NewHeight);                                            
}                      
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following code:

```
CGSize oldSize;

public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
}

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITextView textView = new UITextView(new CGRect(20,20,100,30));
    oldSize = textView.Frame.Size;
    textView.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16);
    textView.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
    textView.Changed += (sender, e) => {

      if(textView.Text.Length!=0&&textView.Text!="")
        {
            CGRect frame = textView.Frame;

            double newHeight = Math.Ceiling(textView.SizeThatFits(new CGSize(oldSize.Width,9999999999)).Height);

            // update the height if the newHeight larger than the old
            if(newHeight >= oldSize.Height)
             {
                textView.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Size.Width, newHeight);
             }
        }   

    };
    View.AddSubview(textView);
}
```